# How do I use the debug console in VSCode？

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I really like the debug console feature in VScode, it makes it a lot easier for me to do Python writing. How do I get it to stay on? Is it possible to write launch.json so that the code runs without closing the run afterwards?

I can use 'time.sleep()' to continue this console on.
Can I edit the'launch.json'?
What are other ways?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the python REPL command line.   fire up python in the terminal in VS Code using the -i option to get an interactive command line.   from there you can play with importing modules, defining functions, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interactive window should work for you. Open an interactive window with the command `Jupyter: Create Interactive Window`

[image]

Or right-click on the code editor interface and select `Run Current File in Python Interactive Window`.

[image]

In this window, you can directly run the code file or write the code and then **shift+enter** to run.

More details can be found in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py#_using-the-python-interactive-window).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to keep the debug console open after the script ends, because the memory is released back to the operating system.

*Edit: as @nigh_anxiety mentioned, setting a breakpoint at the end of the script is probably a more elegant solution.*

---

Old Answer:

Instead, you could wait for user input before exiting, with a line like

```py
input('press enter to quit')
```

at the end of your file.

Comment: or just set a breakpoint on the last line of the script

Comment: These methods are good.